# Unable to open image file saved by flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask API that receives data from PHP. I am getting images as input and I am storing in my download folder. But the problem is that when I open the images, I am getting `Unrecognized image file format`. Here is my code to save an image:

```
imagefile = flask.request.files.get('image', '')
image = imagefile.read()
filename = imagefile.filename
slash_index = filename.rfind('/')
filename = filename[slash_index + 1:]
app.logger.info(slash_index)
app.logger.info(filename)
file_format = request.form.get('format')
app.logger.info(os.path.join(config.online_training_path, filename))
imagefile.save(os.path.join(config.online_training_path, filename)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with it? I am passing jpeg or png files only.

Comment: Could you show me the exception stack?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. The reason is about imagefile.read() function.

Remove the code below and it works.

```
image = imagefile.read()
```